# How do I delete rows in data frame

Tags: r

I'm sure this is a very elementary question... I want to delete four rows in a dataset so that I can do a correlation test against other data. In the dataset I have one column and 12 rows but I only want the first eight rows. My original data looks like this:

```
    Pensacola
A 0.43878650
B 0.08313799
C 0.04348244
D 0.09530939
E 0.04674773
F 0.16009961
G 0.12301393
H 0.05988241
I 0.22225384
J 1.22884931
K 0.89329825
L 0.26534880
```

I want to delete rows I, J, K, and L and still keep the same one-column format. 
I tried the following:

```
row_to_keep = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
Pensacola1 = Pensacola[row_to_keep,]
```

and

```
Pensacola1 <- Pensacola[-c(9:12), ]
```

but both return this

```
[1] 0.43878650 0.08313799 0.04348244 0.09530939 0.04674773
[6] 0.16009961 0.12301393 0.05988241
```

I just want the data to stay in one column with the rownames A-H and column name "Pensacola".
Any help would be great!

Comment: `Pensacola[-c(9:12),,drop=FALSE]` - when you select only one column, R drops the matrix-like structure and returns a vector.

Answer (score -2):

You say that you want your data to be in one column, but this might be a bad idea in case we want to access something individually later. We can have much more control if we break it up into two separate columns. As well, it might make more sense to use a dataframe (it looks like it already is in your question, but lets be totally sure). Let's call them letter and Pensacola.

When we do this, the result is exactly as you want it. When I run it, it comes out like how you like it.

```
my_df=read.table("clipboard") # I read in your data
names(my_df)=c("letter","Pensacola")

row_to_keep = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
Pensacola1 = my_df[row_to_keep,]
> Pensacola1
    letter  Pensacola
1      A 0.43878650
2      B 0.08313799
3      C 0.04348244
4      D 0.09530939
5      E 0.04674773
6      F 0.16009961
7      G 0.12301393
8      H 0.05988241
```